# Fitting: lowering the difference between values

Tags: r, regression, fitting, excel, measurement-error

I have two sets of data: first one is independently observed while the second one is combination of 7 variables. I am trying to assign weights (or betas if this is considered as a multiple regression) and then use Excel's Solver function to reduce the sum of squared differences between the first set of observations and the second (basically RMSE approach).

However, this is not as efficient as I hoped. Are there any other options to accomplish this task either in Excel and/or R?

My independently observed data:

```
0.03%
0.75%
0.02%
0.46%
0.27%
-0.70%
-0.49%
-0.18%
-0.53%
0.21%
```

The variables that are comprise the second data:

```
1.24%   1.57%   0.17%   0.96%   1.08%   1.33%   0.00%
2.13%   3.18%   3.73%   2.43%   2.81%   1.80%   0.00%
-1.41%  -1.13%  0.08%   -0.49%  -0.25%  -0.29%  0.00%
0.63%   1.14%   2.28%   1.51%   1.62%   1.36%   0.00%
0.51%   -0.05%  1.36%   0.66%   0.96%   0.09%   0.00%
-3.22%  -5.46%  -3.46%  -3.63%  -4.53%  -3.58%  0.00%
0.99%   1.87%   -2.44%  1.05%   1.80%   0.59%   0.00%
-0.57%  -1.25%  -0.92%  -0.53%  -0.22%  -1.38%  0.00%
-1.90%  -2.83%  -2.61%  -2.43%  -1.30%  -2.34%  0.00%
-0.10%  -0.10%  1.04%   0.57%   -0.22%  1.66%   0.00%
```

The actual datasets are much bigger than this.

I am not quite sure if my question is clear enough, but ready to expand and give more details if required. Thank you.

Comment: Excel will fit multiple regression using more efficient approaches than solver. I notice you have used the measurement error tag -- do your independent variables (ie the second set) have substantial measurement error?

Comment: @Glen_b, no actually. These errors can be ignored. Can you please elaborate a bit your point re fitting regression?

Comment: "These errors can be ignored." Please give more information what the percentages in the data are. Please excuse me for having doubts that you have actually understood the implications of @Glen_b's question.